# Apache POI Cannot add merged region to an existing merged region

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI 3.17 and in my code i need to merge new cell with existing merged region

```
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1,3,1,1));
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1,4,1,1));
```

Here i created merged region start from row 1 to 3 with column number 1 , then i need to merge new row to be from 1 to 4 .

but it give me this error :

```
Cannot add merged region B2:B5 to sheet because it overlaps with an existing merged region (B2:B4).
```

I'm showing this example because in my code i generate new rows and i need some cells to be merged with above merged region

Comment: Are you attempting to expand the first merged region to be the size of the second merged region?